# C# find highest available youtube resolution on a video

Tags: c#, youtube

I'm making a playlist downloader which downloads every video on the playlist, but so far i can only make it download in 360p. I want to automatically find the highest resolution for the video and download it.

Here is my code:

```
                    IEnumerable<VideoInfo> videoInfos = DownloadUrlResolver.GetDownloadUrls("www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + vid.ToString());

                    VideoInfo video = videoInfos.First(info => info.VideoType == VideoType.Mp4 && info.Resolution == 360);

                    string filename = video.Title;

                    if (video.RequiresDecryption)
                    {
                        DownloadUrlResolver.DecryptDownloadUrl(video);
                    }

                    string invalidChars = new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) + new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars());
                    foreach (char c in invalidChars)
                    {
                        filename = filename.Replace(c.ToString(), "");
                    }

                    var videoDownloader = new VideoDownloader(video, Path.Combine(corpath, filename + video.VideoExtension));


                    Console.Write("\rVideo #{0} is currently being downloaded...", i.ToString());

                    videoDownloader.Execute();
                    i++;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
```

I'm using this library: https://github.com/flagbug/YoutubeExtractor/

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the videoInfos and find the one with the highest available resolution

Remove this line because it fetches only a certain resolution

```
VideoInfo video = videoInfos.First(info => info.VideoType == VideoType.Mp4 && info.Resolution == 360);
```

Add the following code in place

```
int maxResolution = 0;
foreach(var v in videoInfos)
{
  if (v.Resolution > maxResolution)
  {
    maxResolution = v.Resolution;
  }
}
```

and then remember to change the code after that to work for a list instead of a single object